# To deploy those un-readable & nonunderstandable javascript files in a website

Tags: javascript

Alot of javascript files , hard to understand, and they are necessary.  For example

```
Function(a,b){function d(b){return!a(b).parents().andSelf().filter(function(){return a.curCSS(this,"visibility")==="hidden"||a.expr.filters.hidden(this)}).length}function c(b,c){var e=b.nodeName.toLowerCase();if("area"===e){var f=b.parentNode,g=f.name,h;if(!b.href||!g||f.nodeName.toLowerCase()!=="map")return!1;h=a("img[usemap=#"+g+"]")[0];return!!h&&d(h)}return(/input|select|textarea|button|object/.test(e)?!b.disabled:"a"==e?b.href||c:c)&&d(b)}a.ui=a.ui||{};a.ui.version||(a.extend(a.ui,{version:"1.8.18",keyCode:{ALT:18,BACKSPACE:8,CAPS_LOCK:20,COMMA:188,COMMAND:91,COMMAND_LEFT:91,COMMAND_RIGHT:93,CONTROL:17,DELETE:46,DOWN:40,END:35,ENTER:13,ESCAPE:27,HOME:36,INSERT:45,LEFT:37,MENU:93,NUMPAD_ADD:107,NUMPAD_DECIMAL:110,NUMPAD_DIVIDE:111,NUMPAD_ENTER:108,NUMPAD_MULTIPLY:106,NUMPAD_SUBTRACT:109,PAGE_DOWN:34,PAGE_UP:33,PERIOD:190,RIGHT:39,SHIFT:16,SPACE:32,TAB:9,UP:38,WINDOWS:91}}),a.fn.extend({propAttr:a.fn.prop||a.fn.attr,_focus:a.fn.focus,focus:function(b,c){return typeof b=="number"?this.each(function()
```

how do guys find out the exact usage of those javascript files downloaded from web somewhere, Jquery website?

So basically , you got a block of codes , downloaded from somewhere and think what it should do and then implement that?
Do you read documents from Jquery website or whatever website you got from  to understand how to use that block of  codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you read the documentation on the website.  This code is minified to make its file size as small as possible so that the time for your users to download is as short as possible.  You aren't meant to read it.  Optionally, you can often download the unminified source, though documentation is generally more useful than raw source anyway.